# How can I convert C sharp code to MATLAB?

Tags: c#, matlab

I have this C# code and I am trying to convert it to MATLAB code wondering if someone would explain how can it be done in MATLAB.

```
private static byte[] CalcLRC(byte[] cmnd)
{
int i, j, bSize = cmnd.Length;
uint lrc,high,low,CR,LF;
string temp;
byte[] bytes = new byte[((bSize)+4)];
lrc=0x00;
CR = 0x0d;
LF = 0x0a;
//loop through input byte array
for (i=0; i<cmnd.Length; i++)
{
//sum message bytes
lrc = lrc + (uint) cmnd[i];
//insert each message byte into result
bytes[i] = cmnd[i];
}
//remove remainder
if (lrc > 256)
{ lrc = lrc - (uint) (256 * Math.Floor((double) lrc/256));
}
//perform 2's complement on sum
lrc = (ushort)(~lrc);
lrc = lrc + 1;
//remove remainder
if (lrc > 256)
{ lrc = lrc - (uint)(256 * Math.Floor((double)lrc / 256));
}
//split into high and low bits
temp = lrc.ToString("X");
high = (uint)temp[0];
low = (uint)temp[1];
//insert high, low, carriage return, and line feed into result
bytes[(bSize)]=(byte) high;
bytes[(bSize+1)]=(byte) low;
bytes[(bSize+2)]=(byte) CR;
bytes[(bSize + 3)] = (byte) LF;
//return result byte array with input, LRC, CR, LF
return bytes;
```

How can it be converted into MATLAB?

Comment: Where there is a will, there is a way :)

Comment: The way is call : work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can call C# code from matlab so you can use this same method in matlab check this link out for more details :

[Call .NET libraries from Matlab](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-net-libraries-in-matlab.html)

The other way around is for you to learn matlab , it may be worth it